# Android Porting Testing - Ported on meego, Ubuntu, Tizen, Windows, WebOS More

Tags: android

I need your help and sharing of knowledge. I want to test Following Android OS features after porting on MEEGO / Ubuntu / HP webOS on Notebook / tablet / touchscreen mobile.

```
Audio ;
Bluetooth;
Camera;
Display;
GPS;
Input;
Lights;
Media;
Network interfaces;
Power Management;
Radio (Phone);
Storage;
Sensors;
Wifi;
Vibrator;
2D and 3D graphics;
USB;
Memory and Storage;
SIM Toolkit Application (STK);
language ;
Take setting from base OS;
Accelerometers;
Notification Manager;
Memory Leaks;
```

Can you help me to get scenarios and list of application with which we can test Ported OS on MEEGO / Ubuntu / HP webOS on Notebook / tablet / touchscreen mobile ?

Comment: Hi JG. Nice Question :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Android CTS](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html) includes all the tests you may need. Passing CTS means your device or port is "Android compatible".

> We define an "Android compatible" device as one that can run any
>   application written by third-party developers using the Android SDK
>   and NDK. We use this as a filter to separate devices that can
>   participate in the Android app ecosystem, and those that cannot.
>   Devices that are properly compatible can seek approval to use the
>   Android trademark. Devices that are not compatible are merely derived
>   from the Android source code and may not use the Android trademark.

Comment: I want to test Android Porting not an android application testing

Comment: Precisely, you pass CTS then you can ensure your port is "Android compatible"

Comment: Android application testing and Android porting testing is total different

Welcome to the Android Porting Guide
http://code.google.com/android/index.html


Official site provides the SDK, Developer's Guide, Reference, and Android Market for the open source project
http://developer.android.com
http://hsc.com/Portals/0/Uploads/Articles/Android-Porting-on-Embedded-Platform_v2_0633850602027036930.pdf


Android source code or helping out with the open-source project,
http://source.android.com/